# Redshift convert dates to unix timestamps

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, unix-timestamp

I have a column of dates in a Redshift table. I would like the output to be in the form of unix timestamps.
Essentially, I want the opposite of this question: [How to convert epoch to datetime redshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815425/how-to-convert-epoch-to-datetime-redshift)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you show the format of your dates?

Answer (score 9):

Date_part is dead. Use extract() now --

```
SELECT extract(epoch from CURRENT_DATE)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just use `EPOCH` with `DATE_PART`.

```
select date_part(epoch, date_column)
from tbl
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html)

> The Amazon Redshift implementation of EPOCH is relative to 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000 independent of the time zone where the server resides. You might need to offset the results by the difference in hours depending on the time zone where the server is located.