# Unixtime to Timestamp in sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to Convert "632689920000000000"  Unixtime to Timestamp sql.

I already tried

```
dateadd(s,632689920000000000,'19700101')
```

and

```
DATEADD(SECOND, 632689920000000000 / 1000, '19691231 20:00')
```

but it returns irrelevent data in each data!!!

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: it is amazon redshift and data retreived from Mongodb

Comment: What exact timestamp would you expect? If you divide by 10^9 it would result in `632689920` = `1990-01-18 20:12:00`

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [How to convert epoch to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815425/how-to-convert-epoch-to-datetime-redshift)

Comment: it is the correct date for this particular data?

Comment: thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815425/how-to-convert-epoch-to-datetime-redshift solved the issue