# Transform a string column that has date and epoch format values into a date column in postgresql/Tableau prep

Tags: postgresql, date, format, amazon-redshift, epoch

how can I transform a string column that has date and epoch format values into a date column? I'm working on a postgresql / Tableau prep environment.

[Please find attached the example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtlNV.png)

OK this query works:

```
SELECT case 
WHEN len(d.properties__renewal_date__value) > 10 
THEN (timestamp 'epoch' + CAST(NULLIF(d.properties__renewal_date__value, '') AS BIGINT)/1000 * interval '1 second')
ELSE to_date(d.properties__renewal_date__value, 'DD/MM/YYYY') end as renewal_date
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the values into your question instead of using a linked image.  I would say the way to go about this is to create a new `date` column and transform the values in the existing column into it.  The date formats could be done as `DD/MM/YYYY::date`. The epoch as `to_timestamp ( epoch_value)::date`.  Distinguishing them would probably need to be done with regex, which I'm not up to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an encoding of @AdrianKlaver's comment. First determine which is the type of the current value with a regexp match and then transform accordingly.

```sql
select case 
   when "renewal date" ~ '^\d+$' then to_timestamp("renewal date"::double precision)::date
   else to_date("renewal date", 'dd/mm/yyyy')
 end as renewal_date
 from _table;
```

Redshift flavour, epoch value in milliseconds:

```sql
select case 
  when "renewal date" ~ '^\d+$' then 
    ('1970-01-01'::date + ("renewal date"::double precision/1000) * '1 second'::interval)::date
  else 
    to_date("renewal date", 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  end as renewal_date
  from _table;
```

Comment: That is cool. The `to_date` for the date formatted values is unnecessary though. You can just do `"renewal date"::date;`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, you are right. I prefer to_date with format though because it is a bit safer as it does not depend on `SET DATESTYLE` configuration.

Comment: That is true enough.

Comment: I tried the above code and I get this error: Invalid operation: function to_timestamp(numeric) does not exist; Do you know why?

Comment: My omission. The function definition is `to_timestamp(double precision)` or no cast at all, not numeric. Pls. use `to_timestamp("renewal date"::double precision)::date`. I have noticed though that 1553817600000 is a *very large* value for epoch and yields 51208-07-09. `to_timestamp("renewal date"::double precision/1000)::date` yields 21-century dates. Maybe epoch values are in milliseconds?

Comment: Should be *to_timestamp("renewal date"::bigint)::date*, The problem is the precision (seconds, microseconds, ...) and the base date for the epoch (std unix 1970-01-01, but also common (that I have seen anyway) 1900-01-01.   You must get both of these.

Comment: I get the same error -- Invalid operation: function to_timestamp (bigint) does not exist; -- with both bigint and double precision. Could it be because "renewal date" column is a string column?

Comment: No, do not use bigint. The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) is clear - `double precision`, seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00. Could you paste your code?

Comment: my code: `SELECT case when d.properties__renewal_date__value ~ '^\d+$' then to_timestamp(d.properties__renewal_date__value::double precision)::date
else to_date(d.properties__renewal_date__value, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
end as renewal_date FROM hubspot.deals d`. And I get this error "SQL Error [500310] [42883]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function to_timestamp(double precision) does not exist;"

Comment: This query is perfectly fine for recent versions of Postgresql. What database/version are you using?

Comment: I have postgresql version 12 and I am querying Redshift from DBeaver

Comment: Well, that should be it. [Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html) says 'Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL have a number of very important differences that you must be aware of'. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815425/how-to-convert-epoch-to-datetime-redshift)

Comment: I have edited my answer to include Redshift language flavour. You must tag your question 'Redshift' though.

Comment: ok, almost there. I tried your query 
`select case when d.properties__renewal_date__value ~ '^\d+$' then 
('1970-01-01'::date + (d.properties__renewal_date__value::double precision/1000) * '1 second'::interval)::date
else to_date(d.properties__renewal_date__value, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
end as renewal_date
FROM hubspot.deals d`
But I get [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: value for "dd" in source string is out of range; What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Invalid date string in `properties__renewal_date__value` field probably

Comment: Use a `where` clause in your query.

Comment: Hi Stefanov, I haven't fully understood what the problem is. How should I use `where` in your query?